# If $A\subset \mathbb R$ and every subset of $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then $m(A) = 0$ (Rudin's RCA)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

I need help understanding certain parts of the proof described below.

> **Theorem 2.22 (Rudin)**: If $A\subset \mathbb R$ and every subset of $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then $m(A) = 0$
> **Proof**: We shall use the fact that $\mathbb R$ is a group, relative to addition. Let $\mathbb Q$ be
> the subgroup that consists of the rational numbers, and let $E$ be a set that contains exactly one point from each coset of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$. Then $E$ has
> the following two properties:
> (a) $(E + r) \cap (E + s) = \varnothing$ if $r \in \mathbb Q$, $s\in\mathbb Q$, $r\neq s$.
> (b) Every $x \in\mathbb R$ lies in $E + r$ for some $r \in\mathbb Q$.
> To prove (a), suppose $x \in (E+r)\cap (E+s)$. Then $x = y + r = z + s$ for some $y\in E, z\in E,y\ne z$. But $y-z = s-r\in\mathbb Q$, so that $y$ and $z$ lie in the same coset of $\mathbb Q$,  a contradiction.

1. Cosets of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$ look like $\mathbb Q + x$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. I agree that $y-z\in\mathbb Q$ means $y$ and $z$ are in the same coset of $\mathbb Q$, but why is this a contradiction?

> To prove (b), let $y$ be the point of $E$ that lies in the same coset as $x$, put $r = x - y$.
> Fix $t\in \mathbb Q$, for the moment, and put $A_t = A \cap (E+t)$. By hypothesis, $A_t$ is measurable. Let $K\subset A_t$ be compact, let $H$ be the union of the translates $K + r$, where $r$ ranges over $\mathbb Q \cap [0, 1]$. Then $H$ is bounded, hence $m(H) < \infty$.

2. How do we know that we can find a compact set contained in $A_t$? Moreover, why is $H$ bounded?

> Since $K \subset E + t$, (a) shows that the sets $K + r$ are pairwise disjoint. Thus $m(H) = \sum_r m(K + r)$. But $m(K + r) = m(K)$. It follows that $m(K) = 0$. This holds for every compact $K \subset A_t$. Hence $m(A_t) = 0$. Finally, (b) shows that $A = \bigcup A_t$ where $t$ ranges over $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q$ is countable, we conclude that $m(A) = 0$.

3. Trying to see why the sets $K+r$ are disjoint. Suppose they aren't. Then, for $r,s\in\mathbb Q$, consider $x \in (K+r)\cap (K+s)$. $x = k_1 + r = k_2 + s$ for some $k_1,k_2\in K$. So, $k_1 - k_2 = s - r \in \mathbb Q$. Where's the contradiction, and how do we use (a)?
4. Using $m(K+r) = m(K)$ (translation invariance of $m$) we get $m(H) = \sum_r m(K)$. To conclude that $m(K) = 0$, I noticed that the index set over which we sum is infinite, namely $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$, but $m(H) < \infty$. If $m(K) > 0$, we have a contradiction. Now why is $m(A_t) = 0$?

Hints are fine, detailed solutions aren't necessary. Just anything that helps me answer my questions works!

Comment: Regarding your first question, by definition, $E$ contains exactly one point from each coset of $\mathbb Q$. So if $y$ and $z$ are the in the same coset of $\mathbb Q$, it can't be true that $y \neq z$. But if $y = z$, then $r = s$.

Comment: Regarding your second question, $K$ is *any* compact set contained in $A_t$. In the worst case, even if $A_t$ is empty, $\emptyset$ is a compact set contained in $A_t$. And if $A_t$ is nonempty, then any singleton contained in $A_t$ is a compact subset of $A_t$. So certainly $A_t$ contains subsets that are compact.

Comment: $H$ is bounded because it's contained in $K + [0,1]$, and both $K$ and $[0,1]$ are bounded. ($K$ is bounded because it's compact.)

Comment: For the fourth question, $A_t$ is assumed to be measurable, and the inner measure is proved to be $0$. So the measure of $A_t$ should also be $0$.

Comment: For the third question, you are picking subsets from disjoint sets respectively, so certainly they should be disjoint. Otherwise the supersets will intersect each other, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @KenHung ($4$th question): We know that $\mu(E) = \sup\{\mu(K): K\subset E, K \text{ compact} \}$ for every open set $E$, and for every $E\in\mathfrak M$ with $\mu(E) < \infty$. To use inner regularity for $A_t$, we must show that $\mu(A_t) < \infty$ or that $A_t$ is open. How did you conclude?

Comment: @KenHung I don't understand the explanation for the $3$rd question still, could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, @Bungo for answering the first two questions!

Comment: @epsilon-emperor I don’t think you need inner regularity here. If a set is measurable then its inner and outer measure coincide, and its measure is just the inner (or outer) measure.

Comment: I'm afraid Rudin (at least so far) has treated measures differently, and not introduced the terms *inner measure* and *outer measure*. Perhaps there is some other way out? @KenHung

Comment: Sure. Maybe I need some time to search the book.

Comment: No worries, thank you!

Comment: I guess I have found a way out. By Theorem 2.20(b), every Lebesgue measurable set can be approximated by a $G_\delta$ set, which is a countable intersection of open sets. The inner regularity can thus be applied.